# c++ Defining copy assignment in derived class

Tags: c++, class, copy, operator-overloading, copy-assignment

So I have the following simple code

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual int GetX() const = 0;
  virtual int GetY() const = 0; 
  virtual Base& operator=(const Base&) = 0;
protected:
  int x;

};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived(int a = 0, int b = 0):y(b){x=a;};
  Base& operator=(const Base&);

  int GetX() const{return x;}
  int GetY() const{return y;}
  void Print(){std::cout << x << y << std::endl;}
private:
  int y;
};

Base& Derived::operator=(const Base& t)
{
  y = t.GetY();
  x = t.GetX();
  return *this;
}

int main()
{
  Derived A(1,2);
  Derived B;
  B = A;
  A.Print();
}
```

And my problem is with the definitios of the operator = as I get the following error, unless I comment the line B=A:

```
In function `Derived::operator=(Derived const&)':
File.C:(.text._ZN7DerivedaSERKS_[_ZN7DerivedaSERKS_]+0x1f): undefined reference to `Base::operator=(Base const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried many workarounds with the copy assignment but nothing works. I need it defined in the Base class because I'll want another Derived class (derived2) and ideally I would be able to even equal between derived classes.

EDIT: Pasted the wrong code

Comment: Trust me, you really don't want to make `op=` virtual. Also, make any 1-argument-ctor `explicit` unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: `y(b){x=a;}` interesting. Why not add constructor to Base and call it in Derived initialization list?

Comment: I didn't really pay attention to simplifying the constructors as it was not quite the issue. I'm using g++ 4.8.2. Why is making op= virtual so problematic?

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't implement `Derived::operator=(Derived const &)`, the compiler gives you a default one which calls `Base::operator=(Base const &)`, which doesn't exist.

You must implement either `Derived::operator=(Derived const &)` or `Base::operator=(Base const &)` if you want `B = A` to compile and link.

You can do `B = static_cast <Base const&> (A);`.